# I cant change the string to int in cpp

Tags: c++

I tried to solve a problem using recursion and the number given was in a form of `std::string` and so in the base case I tried returning the number by converting it to `int` using the `stoi` function but the compiler gave an absurd error.

```cpp
int solve(string a, int i, int k, string s) {
    int n = a.length();
    if (i == n and i != k) return 1000;
    if (i == k) {
        cout << stoi(s);
        int t = stoi(s);
        return t;
    }
    int incl = solve(a, i + 1, k, s + a[i]);
    int excl = solve(a, i + 1, k, s);
    return min(incl, excl);
}
```

The compiler said

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
```

Comment: I suggest printing out the strings you try to convert with `stoi`. It should become obvious what the problem is if you do.

Comment: The untold root of this problem is that "number given in a form of `std::string`" is done so because the real data not-posted with this question  is some value well-outside the range of the platform `int`.

Comment: *but the compiler gave an absurd error* -- First, it isn't the compiler giving you the error -- the compiler's job is to build your program, not run your program.  Instead, it is your program and faulty call of `stoi` that is giving the error.

Comment: Adding to what @TedLyngmo said, `std::invalid_argument` is usually thrown by `stoi()` if the characters in a string do not represent a valid integer. Your best bet here is to print out the strings you are trying to convert. You could potentially traverse the string and use `is_digit()` in a for-loop, to check if it's valid throw some error, and then handle it in the function or elsewhere

Comment: [I duplicated the issue very easily](https://godbolt.org/z/87h1ocv8o).  Now, take the code you see at the link, and call `solve` with the arguments you are claiming you are calling it with.  Also, calling the error "absurb" gives the indication that you believed that the program is correct, and it is something else that is faulty.  Wrong.  No matter how much you may believe the program is correct, the computer is running your program not caring what you *may* believe is correct, but the actual code you wrote, without caring if you made bugs.

Comment: `a` isn't modified anywhere at all, thus you should accept by const reference to avoid needless copies. Same, slightly less obviously, applies to `s` as well; appending something to `s` produces a new temporary string, and again you avoid a copy of.

Answer (score 0):

Fist, as noted in the comments, this is not a compiler error. Rather it is a [exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) thrown at runtime.

According to [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), `std::stoi()` throws `std::invalid_argument` "if no conversion could be performed."

This means that whatever the contents of `s` are, it cannot be properly converted into an integer.

It's really impossible to know why the conversion failed without knowing the contents of `s`, but here are some possible reasons:

1. `s` contains text characters such as "asdf120"
2. `s` contains comma separated values like "1, 13, 25"
3. Some other reason I'm not thinking of.

I suggest creating some debug printout containing the value of `s` to someplace like `std::cout` and make sure it is a proper integer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::invalid_argument` is thrown by `stoi()` if the characters in a string do not represent a valid integer. Assuming your algorithm is correct, one way to avoid the runtime error would be to add a check (using the `std::is_digit`) if the `char` in the `std::string` is actually a number.

**Side note:**  You never check if `s` is empty...

---

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdexcept>

int solve(std::string a, int i, int k, std::string s) {
    int n = a.length();
    if (i == n and i != k) return 1000;
    if (i == k) {
        bool isValid = !s.empty();
        for (char c : s) {
            if (!std::isdigit(c)) {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isValid) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("[invalid int representation]]");
            //or

            //return -1;
        }

        std::cout << s;
        int t = std::stoi(s);
        return t;
    }
    int incl = solve(a, i + 1, k, s + a[i]);
    int excl = solve(a, i + 1, k, s);
    return std::min(incl, excl);
}

int main() {
    try {
        solve("abc", 1, 1, "xyz"); //using @PaulMcKenzie's example
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        std::cerr << "{error}: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        //...other logic
    }
}
```

`s` is traversed using a range based `for`-loop, if the `char` in the `std::string` is invalid it throws `std::invalid_argument`, which is handled in main.